# Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{ro.vst.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}

Tags: android, testing

here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/vst/tree/unable-to-find-instrumentation), when i run following code,

```
public class KernelTest {
    @Test
    public void testM() {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

It raise:

```
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{ro.vst.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've found the solution: in android studio 1.5, whether I specify runner or not, avd side will generate a package name with "my_pkg_name.test/runner_name", the solution steps are:

- run android test once
- I get "Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{ro.vst.test/**android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner**}"
- run `adb shell pm list instrumentation`, find pkg relative instrument
- I get "instrumentation:ro.vst.test/**com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner**"
- the two TestRunner are different, so I specify TestRunner in build.gradle like following

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
```

- now run again, it should work